# Frames are not seen in BGR scale (OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, slam

I'm trying to write the code for SLAM using OpenCV from scratch. While I'm trying to show detected features from each frame in colored-circular mark, I've got a problem showing this in color.

Summary

- For `goodFeaturesToTrack` function, `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.BGR2GRAY)` process should be done first.
- and then after `goodFeaturesToTrack` process, I've tried to indicate features in colored circle in frame.
- So, I converted frame to `cv2.GRAY2BGR`

I expected colored circular marks in the frame but this is not currently being seen.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

W = 1920//2
H = 1080//2


def process(image):
    image = cv.resize(image,(W,H))
    image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    corners = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(image, 3000, 0.01, 3)
    corners = np.int0(corners)
    image_copy = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    for i in corners:
        x, y = i.ravel()
        cv.circle(image_copy, (x,y), color = (0,0,255), radius=3)
        #cv.circle(image, (x,y), 3, 255, -1)
     
    return image_copy



if __name__ == "__main__":
    cap = cv.VideoCapture("../test/test_countryroad.mp4")

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            frame = process(frame)
            frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
            cv.imshow('frame', frame)
            if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

But the error comes out like below after I run this code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./slam.py", line 34, in <module>
    frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /home/hkim/opencv/opencv-4.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::impl::{anonymous}::CvtHelper<VScn, VDcn, VDepth, sizePolicy>::CvtHelper(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int) [with VScn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<1>; VDcn = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<3, 4>; VDepth = cv::impl::{anonymous}::Set<0, 2, 5>; cv::impl::{anonymous}::SizePolicy sizePolicy = (cv::impl::<unnamed>::SizePolicy)2; cv::InputArray = const cv::_InputArray&; cv::OutputArray = const cv::_OutputArray&]'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 3
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is grayscale and thus when you are trying to draw coloured circles in the image, you can't as there is only one channel as opposed to the expected three for colour images.  What you need to do is create a separate copy of the frame so you can run the interest point detection on that, get the corners and draw them on the colour version of the image instead.

```py
def process(image):
    image = cv.resize(image,(W,H))
    # Change
    image_copy = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Change
    corners = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(image_copy, 3000, 0.01, 3)
    corners = np.int0(corners)

    for i in corners:
        x, y = i.ravel()
        cv.circle(image, (x,y), color = (0,0,255), radius=3)

    return image
```

Finally in your `while` loop, because the image is now in colour, you can remove the conversion statement from grayscale to colour as the function returns the image already in colour.

```py
   while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            frame = process(frame)
            # Remove the line below
#            frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
            cv.imshow('frame', frame)
            if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
but I had tried this before.. the error comes out following this statement.             

" Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 3
"

Comment: @HenryKIM That's because you need to remove that statement in your while loop.  The image is already colour once you converted it.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: finally error is solved. But I wonder why frame is still in gray scale with colored mark. I want to see colored mark in RGB scaled frame.

Comment: You need to make a copy of the input colour image. You didn't tell me this was your intent. I'll edit... One more time.

Comment: Really appreciate it! I didn't notice I didn't mention my intend. I resolved it thanks to you :)

Comment: Not a problem! If your problem is resolved please consider accepting this answer to let the community know you no longer need help. That can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of this answer on the left beside the up and down voting buttons. Good luck!

Comment: Yes I did it, thanks for guiding new stackoverflower:)